# WhiteSource was unable to scan your repository. Please connect to your WhiteSource account by navigating to Organization settings > WhiteSource tab

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, whitesource-bolt

I cloned the repo: https://github.com/HoussemDellai/WebAppWithDatabaseDemo.git to Azure Dev Ops project and created a CI-CD pipeline. In the pipeline I added a task for WhiteSource Bolt based on the instructions mentioned at : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/performing-vulnerability-assessment-in-azure-devops/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjmvuNth1GE. I then tried to trigger the build pipeline and came across error at the WhiteSource task level :

```
WhiteSource was unable to scan your repository. Please connect to your WhiteSource account by navigating to Organization settings > WhiteSource tab.
```

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your whitesource bolt account and generate an activation key from the integrate menu. Apply that key in the in the Organization settings > WhiteSource tab.

Comment: Thanks @lp_nave for your response. In this case I am using free version of WhiteSourceBolt (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whitesource.whiteSource-bolt-v2) . I tried to figure out how to create an account but no luck on it. On clicking the WhiteSource  under Extensions under Organization Settings I see an error saying : Please connect your organization to an Azure AD via Organization Settings > Azure Active Directory.

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro same here

Comment: Thanks @lp_nave. I tried to follow all the details shared by you and it helped me to resolve the issue :)